# I have a map of inputs inside a square bracket and I want to read it it in hive

Tags: debugging, hadoop, hive

Input File:

```
[Tom,123,0,jump]
[jerry,345,1,run]
```

I want to read the above input in hive,
my ddl is

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.tomjerrry 
>   ( name string, id
>   int, isGood int,  activity string )
>
> row format delimited fields terminated by ','
>
> LOCATION '/user/myname/sample.txt'

When i try reading , 
Select name from db1.tomjerrry

I get,

> [Tom
>
> [jerry

How do I remove the square bracket in the hive output.?

Comment: still facing issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ESCAPED BY '['

ie

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db1.tomjerrry ( name ARRAY<string>, id int, isGood int, activity string )

    row format delimited fields terminated by ',' ESCAPED BY '[';

    LOCATION '/user/myname/sample.txt'
```

Or  **update CSV file** remove [.

Comment: Thanks It helps, sorry for the delay